# How to put explicit lifetime bound on Self for associated constant?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait which I want to have an associated constant on, where the constant will be a slice of the type that implements the trait. Something like this:

```rust
trait A: Sized {
    const VALUES: &'static [Self];
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {
    b: u8,
}

impl A for B {
    const VALUES: &'static [B] = &[B { b: 1 }];
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct C {
    c: usize,
}

impl A for C {
    const VALUES: &'static [C] = &[C { c: 4 }];
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", B::VALUES);
    println!("{:?}", C::VALUES);
}
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `Self` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     const VALUES: &'static [Self];
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `Self: 'static`...
note: ...so that the reference type `&'static [Self]` does not outlive the data it points at
```

How is that lifetime bound expressed for an associated constant? If it's relevant, I'm using latest `rustc` stable (`1.42.0`), and the 2018 edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you probably want to simply add `'static` to the supertrait bound on `A`:

```
trait A: Sized + 'static {
    const VALUES: &'static [Self];
}
```

You may instead put the `Self: 'static` bound only on `VALUES`:

```
trait A: Sized {
    const VALUES: &'static [Self] where Self: 'static;
}
```

This means that you can still implement `A` for non-`'static` types, but such types won't have a `VALUES` associated constant, so it's only practical to do so if the trait `A` has some other useful property independent of `VALUES`. (Also, in order to use `T::VALUES` in generic code, you have to bound `T: A + 'static` instead of merely `T: A`.)

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer! I could have sworn I'd tried the first one (not quite sure what I did instead), but definitely wasn't close to the right syntax for the latter, so that's really helpful!